# How to prove that $A^TA$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a linear system $Ax=b$ with the matrix $A\in \Bbb R^{m\times n}, m>n$ and all the columns have a full rank, so there 
linearly independent.

I want to prove that $A^TA$ is orthogonal, hope it is?:)

What I know:

1) $A^TA$ is symmetric

2) It is $x^TA^TAx>0$.

Proof: Be $y = A*x$ and because $A$ has a full rank => $y = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$. We get $x^T A^T A x = (\|y\|_2)^2 > 0$ for all $y\neq 0$, so $x \neq 0$.

=> $A^TA$ is positive definite => has an inverse (regular) and has a full rang.

Problem: I have no idea how to prove that $A^TA$ is orthogonal.
Can you help?

The start could be something like.

Be $Q :=A^TA$. Show $Q^{-1}Q = E$ <=> $(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA =E $

I proved before, that $A^TA$ has an inverse, so $(A^TA)^{-1}$ exists.

Could $(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA = E$ be trivial than?

P.S.
I'm so sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No, $A^TA$ need not be orthogonal. Have you tried any _examples_? One can give a simple $2\times 2$ counterexample...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich     Hey, yes I tried  some, but It looks like the wrong ones:) Do you have one?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I can not find a counterexample, any tips how to find one?

Comment: I thought you'd posted a counterexample in a comment  - that comment has disappeared. Anyway, $A=[1,1]$. Or $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Your A is not in Form $A\in \Bbb R^{m\times n}, m>n$. 
And I deleted my comment because I thought  I'm wrong with everything, but that was not true:)

Comment: So $m$ has to be min $3$ and $n$ min $2$ because we want a matrix.

Comment: @JulianeB then consider instead
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1\\0&0}.
$$
In fact, we find that $A^TA$ will be orthogonal if and only if $A$ has orthonormal columns, which is to say that $A^TA = E$. Indeed, a (symmetric) positive definite matrix is orthogonal if and only if it is the identity matrix.

Comment: @JulianeB: A $2\times 1$ matrix is a matrix, too.

Comment: I agree with David.  If you had tried one example (in your case, a $3 \times 2$ example), then it is highly unlikely that the resulting matrix $A^TA$ would be orthogonal.  The reasonable conclusion, then, is that you didn't test any $3 \times 2$ examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:** A (symmetric) positive definite matrix is orthogonal if and only if it is the identity matrix.

**Proof:** Suppose that $M$ is positive definite and orthogonal.  Then $M^TM = M^2 = E$.  However, $M$ is the unique positive definite square root of $M^2$.  So, we have
$$
M = \sqrt{M^2} = \sqrt{E} = E. \qquad \square
$$

Consequently, $A^TA$ can only be orthogonal if $A^TA = E$.  This will occur if and only if the columns of $A$ are orthonormal, that is to say mutually orthogonal with length $1$.  So, there are many examples for which $A^TA$ fails to be orthogonal.